# MS SQL output sales transaction and inventory

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help to show only sales item (IF column btLatinAbbrev = Sales) and inventory item (IF the QTY column is 1).

And I want one more column called Datatype based on the above condition. IF the column btLatinAbbrev = Sales then column Datatype should be filled with S (S mean sale) and IF the QTY column contain 1 then column Datatype should be filled with I (i for inventory).

below is the exported table view **FROM MS SQL 2008**

```
+---------------+-----------------+-----+----------+
| btLatinAbbrev |       SN        | Qty | DATATYPE |
+---------------+-----------------+-----+----------+
| Sales         | 355274073159784 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073190128 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073158679 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073166904 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073159925 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073159255 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073158679 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073166904 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073190128 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073159255 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073159925 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073158679 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073159230 |   1 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073157333 |   1 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073158851 |   1 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073166904 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073190128 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073159784 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073159255 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073158828 |   1 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073159925 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073159784 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073158679 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073166904 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073190128 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073159255 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073159925 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073158679 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073159230 |   1 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073157333 |   1 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073158851 |   1 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073166904 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073190128 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073159784 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073159255 |   0 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073158828 |   1 |          |
| Pur.          | 355274073159925 |   0 |          |
| Sales         | 355274073159784 |   0 |          |
+---------------+-----------------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT btLatinAbbrev,
       Qty,
       CASE WHEN btLatinAbbrev = 'Sales' THEN 'S'
            ELSE 'I'
       END AS DataType
FROM   myTable
WHERE  btLatinAbbrev = 'Sales' OR Qty = 1;
```

You did not specify what to do in case a record is both a sales item and an inventory item.
The query above defines it a sales item.

Comment: I have one more column called salesdate. how can I show the sales of yesterday with inventory. If there is a sales yesterday it should show that sales with inventory. If there is no sales no need to ouput the sale but need Inventory with yesterday sale...

Answer (score 0):

## Solution Type1

```
with CTE as 
(
select 'sales' 'btLatinAbbrev ','355274073159784' 'SN','0' 'Qty'
union all
select 'sales','355274073159785','1'
union all
select 'pur','355274073159786','2'
union all
select 'Pur','355274073159787','0'
)

select btLatinAbbrev, 
case when btLatinAbbrev IN ('sales') and QTY >0 then 'S'
     when btLatinAbbrev IN ('Pur') and QTY >0 then 'I' end 'Datatype'
 from cte
```

## 2 Solution Type2

```
with CTE as 

    (
    select 'sales' 'btLatinAbbrev ','355274073159784' 'SN','0' 'Qty'
    union all
    select 'sales','355274073159785','1'
    union all
    select 'pur','355274073159786','2'
    union all
    select 'Pur','355274073159787','0'
    )

    select btLatinAbbrev, sn,
    case when btLatinAbbrev IN ('sales') then 'S' --else 'S' 
         when btLatinAbbrev IN ('Pur')  then 'I' end 'DAtatype'
     from cte where qty > 0
```